# How to split a string not losing separator characters using BCL in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, string, split, separator

I need to split a string based on some character array of separators and not lose these separators in string. I.e.:

```
string: "Hello world!"
separators: " !"
result: ("Hello", " ", "world", "!")
```

Of course, i can write something that goes through that string and returns me needed result, but isn't there something already allowing me to do this, like magically configured `String.Split`?

**Upd:** I need to solution without regexp, because it is very slow for me.

Comment: One detail: if the source string is " ", what output would you expect (an empty string and a separator, or only a single space)?

Comment: @Dream: I think using regex is faster than using a custom solution "if you are not tended to use some unsafe context and pointers"... moreover by using regex you are safe from from unpredictable bugs that my occurred in the custom solution..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular expression:

```
string[] parts = Regex.Split(myString, yourPattern);
```

Test:

```
string[] parts = Regex.Split("Hello World!", "(!| )");
```

output:

```
Hello
" "//just space
World
!
""//empty string
```

Comment: I think you shouldn't use `IgnoreCase` if you don't need it. Potentially costs performance. Also: It does exactly not answer the question.

Comment: -1 removed again. Though the OP also splits at ' '. Though2 it could need some explanation for why the parentheses are important.

Comment: @Jalal Aldeen Saa'd, look to my upd about regexp

Answer (score 2):

A linq solution:

```
var s = "Hello world!";
char[] separators = { ' ', '!' };

string current = string.Empty;
List<string> result = s.Aggregate(new List<string>(), (list, ch) =>
    {
        if (separators.Contains(ch))
        {
            list.Add(current);
            list.Add(ch.ToString());
            current = string.Empty;
        }
        else current += ch;
        return list;
    }, list => list);
```

Answer (score 2):

This would be a purely procedural solution:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Tokenize(string text, string separators)
{
    int startIdx = 0;
    int currentIdx = 0;

    while (currentIdx < text.Length)
    {
        // found a separator?
        if (separators.Contains(text[currentIdx]))
        {
            // yield a substring, if it's not empty
            if (currentIdx > startIdx)
                yield return text.Substring(startIdx, currentIdx - startIdx);

            // yield the separator
            yield return text.Substring(currentIdx, 1);

            // mark the beginning of the next token
            startIdx = currentIdx + 1;
        }

        currentIdx++;
    }
}
```

Note that this solution avoids returning **empty** tokens. For example, if the input is:

```
string input = "test!!";
```

calling `Tokenize(input, "!")` will return three tokens:

```
test
!
!
```

If the requirement is that two adjacent separators should have an empty token between them, then the `if (currentIdx > startIdx)` condition should be removed.